# How do I tighten up the margin between the rows?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to pull in the space between the rows, and a negative margin is working for the left/right margins, but not the up/down margins.

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rec {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 50px;    
}

#wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 5px;
  min-height: 5px;
  margin: -3px;  
  background-color: white;  
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<section class="rec center" id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>   
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
</section>
```

Comment: What is your end result supposed to look like? Because you're probably better off just using `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;` on the `section`, and ditch the `margin` on the `div`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `float:left` property in wrapper class and it did the trick

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.rec {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 50px; 

}

#wrapper div {
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 5px;
  min-height: 5px;
  padding:0.1em;
  background-color: white;  
  cursor: default;
  white-space:0;
}
```

```html
<section class="rec center" id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the container into a grid, and you can control how many items you want on each row, and how much space you want between rows and columns. I set the rows to `grid-row-gap: 5px`:

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}

body{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  max-width: 120px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

#wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid" id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>   
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 0.7;` to your section class.

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rec {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 50px; 
  line-height: 0.7;
}

#wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 5px;
  min-height: 5px;
  margin: -3px;  
  background-color: white;  
  cursor: default;
  line-height:0.7;
}
```

```html
<section class="rec center" id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>   
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
</section>
```